# what grids are compatible with Angular4? mainly for sorting, filtering the table

Tags: angular, grid-search

Tried with `ag-grid` which is the best fit, `package.json` is like this:

```
"ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
"ag-grid-angular": "^14.0.0",
"ag-grid-community": "^14.0.0",
"angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
"@syncfusion/ej2": "^16.3.31",
"@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids": "^16.3.31",
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’re already using some kind of Ui component you could go with angular material or  taiga both come with pagination and sorting functionality.
In fact most tables in UI libraries offer these basic features. Implementing a filter on any UI component should be too difficult either.

On the other hand if you are looking for some advanced functionality then it’s better to go for AG-Grid